# Jquery not working fine with out an alert box

Tags: jquery, alert

Please ignore if I am asking a repeated or common question.
Jquery is working fine if i have an alert in the code.
Example:

```
var selectedEvent = jQuery("#DemoEvents").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');  
var imagePath = jQuery("#DemoEvents").getCell(selectedEvent, 9);  
var locationArr = imagePath.split("rel");  
var evtId = jQuery("#DemoEvents").getCell(selectedEvent, 0);  
**alert(evtId);**  
var anchorId = jQuery("#DemoEvents").getCell(selectedEvent, 7);
jQuery('#tr_anchorId .FormElement').val(anchorId);  

jQuery("#tr_anchorId .FormElement option[value='"+evtId+"']").remove();
```

is working fine...  and....

```
var selectedEvent = jQuery("#DemoEvents").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');  
var imagePath = jQuery("#DemoEvents").getCell(selectedEvent, 9);  
var locationArr = imagePath.split("rel");  
var evtId = jQuery("#DemoEvents").getCell(selectedEvent, 0);  
**//alert(evtId);**  
var anchorId = jQuery("#DemoEvents").getCell(selectedEvent, 7);  
jQuery('#tr_anchorId .FormElement').val(anchorId);  

jQuery("#tr_anchorId .FormElement option[value='"+evtId+"']").remove();
```

is not working. any ideas please give.

Comment: Please could you explain what *happens*, and what's *meant* to happen. How does it not work, or break? Could you post a demo to [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar to show us your code (not) working?

Comment: Well, according to that code you posted, you'll need to change `**//alert(evtId);**`  to `//**alert(evtId);**`

Comment: @Dutchie432 that's potentially markdown formatting to make the line bold, but if those asterisks were in the code, you're right the JS engines would probably fall over at that point. Since the top snippet has them, that might not be the issue.

Comment: @Dutchie432: I think he just tried to make it bold.

Comment: do you make any asynchronous calls before the alert? any errors in console

Comment: @Alec, @ David Thomas, I am using this code in my jqgrid application. Here I am trying to set a value to the list box and removing a value from a list box. here if I have alert means it is working fine otherwise not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason it should not be working is because there is an AJAX call in your method.

Placing an `alert` on this snippet gives time for that AJAX call to fetch your data. Otherwise it won't work because the snippet runs out before your AJAX call returns.

If there is an AJAX Call then you should ideally be writing the rest of the code in its call back method and this would solve the issue.

P.S: I was wrong about `getCell`. Its a [jqGrid method](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods). Sorry.

Comment: I am just preparing an edit form. After preparing it I will make an ajax call. Before that there is no ajax call.